# ¿Por qué file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(fs) falla sin error y deja el archivo vacio en c#?

Tags: c#, blazor

Estoy intentando subir un archvivo utilizando Blazor y c# con las siguientes sentencias y me deja creado el archivo con 0 bytes y no me genera ningún error que pueda atrapar con try-catch

```
try{
   await using FileStream fs = new FileStream(rutaNombreNuevoArchivo, FileMode.Create);
   if (file.Size < maxTamArchivo)
   {
        await file.OpenReadStream(maxTamArchivo).CopyToAsync(fs);
   }
}catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Message);
}
```

El error:

> Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given).

Comment: Encontré este error en la consola:  Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given).'.